# How to format request for POST in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a POST param like:

```
var requestJson = $@"{{""positionsQuery"":{{""positionDate"":[""{positionDate.Date:yyyyMMdd}""]}},""measures"":[""margin""]}}";
```

This produces `\` so Fiddler shows it as

```
"{\"positionsQuery\":{\"positionDate\":[\"20181119\"]},\"measures\":[\"margin\"]}"
```

The request fails as a result. What I need to make is work is

```
{"positionsQuery":{"positionDate":["20181119"]},"measures":["margin"]}
```

Before this I tried `Json.Net'

```
        var request = new { PositionsQuery = new { PositionDate = new [] { positionDate.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") } }, Measures = new [] { "margin" }};
        var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
        var response = (await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, requestJson).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

Still the `\` are there causing problem (Fiddler screenshot).

[image: Fiddler screenshot]

Thanks!
How can I format the request ?

Comment: What does the error say? Can you show the code that's posting the request?

Comment: the debugger will show it as an escaped string.

Answer (score 1):

Don't manually build a JSON string. It's much cleaner to build the object and serialize it.

```
var requestJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
        positionsQuery = new
        {
            positionDate = positionDate.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
        },
        measures = new []{"margin"}
    });
```

Comment: I was trying this before but still the service was throwing error as bad request. I will try again.

Comment: What overload of PostAsync is that using? I don't see one that takes a string. It looks like it's serializing an already serialized string.

Comment: It is a wrapper method, i have added the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` in there and that fixed the problem